# access php file return 404 code but success on other file

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I was running four images of docker, they are php 7.3, nginx 1.17, redis 5.0.5 and mysql 8.0, all of these was pulled from official images on DockerHub. then I create a `docker-compose.yml` file, it seems like following:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/../:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - $PWD/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    links:
      - php
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - net-app
    container_name: nginx

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: "--innodb_use_native_aio=0"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/mysql/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
      - $PWD/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d
    networks:
      - net-app
    container_name: mysql


  php:
    image: php
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9501:9501"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/../:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
    networks:
      - net-app
    container_name: php

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/redis/datadir:/data
    networks:
      - net-app
    container_name: redis

networks:
  net-app:
    driver: bridge
```

then I create a project with `info.php` and `test.txt`

there is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  test.site.com;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/test/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/test;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   php:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME
 /var/www/html/test/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

after configured and started docker, I access url `test.site.com/info.php` and got an nginx 404 error page, but I can access `test.site.com/test.txt`. It returned the text in the file. Why? I attached into php container and run `php` command, it works. I don't know reason, I tried some way but failed, and I cannot find the answer on google.

**UPDATE**
there is some detail, I pulled php:5.6 about 3 weeks ago, I copied `docker-compose.yml` file and modify the repo/tag of php section. but l cannot start php successfully, It was always on restarting status, then I add the config of `tty: true`, then the php container could keep on running

**More Update**

if I delete following:

```
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/test;
}
```

error page become to **502 bad gateway**

Comment: I think you want to run PHP-FPM, instead of just PHP-CLI in the PHP container. Try set `image: php:fpm` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to run PHP-FPM, instead of just PHP-CLI in the PHP container. In `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
    php:
        image: php:fpm
```

Comment: In my case, I used `php:7.3.6-fpm`